# What is the difference between Si pixel and Si strips used in CMS Inner tracker at CERN?

Tags: experimental-physics, electronics, large-hadron-collider

What is the difference between Si pixel and Si strips used in CMS at CERN? Both are used for tracking and as the CERN website mentions, they are also based on the same working principles. Or are they actually based on different principles?

Answer (score 1):

Each pixel covers a smaller area, therefore the pixel detector has better spatial resolution. (That's also why it's the closest detector to the collision point, where particle tracks are more "dense".)